# Is there a way to turn off instance through Oracle Cloud android app?

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I've installed Oracle Cloud app with hope that I can manage my instances(turn them off, on or restart) but I can't see such option. Is there a way to do that within app or It's just a health status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present you can not turn things off and on again via the app. Currently (30 Nov 2020), you can view details about the following types of resources in the mobile app.

Compute instances
Block volumes
Object Storage
Load balancers
Autonomous Transaction Processing
Autonomous Data Warehouse

You can find its current documentation via here - https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/GSG/Concepts/mobile.htm